# Where in the C++ standard does it state that the default constructor is not generated when the copy constructor is deleted?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, language-lawyer

The C++11 program

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(Foo const &) = delete;
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
}
```

generates the error

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 junk.cpp -o junk
junk.cpp: In function 'int main()':
junk.cpp:6:9: error: no matching function for call to 'Foo::Foo()'
junk.cpp:6:9: note: candidate is:
junk.cpp:2:5: note: Foo::Foo(const Foo&) <deleted>
junk.cpp:2:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Now, it looks like the default constructor was prevented from being generated because the copy constructor was deleted.  I'm going to assume this is the expected behavior, but where in the C++ standard does it specify that the default constructor should not be generated when the copy constructor is deleted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From N3485 §12.1 [class.ctor]/5:

> If there is no user-declared constructor for class X, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted (8.4).

`Foo(Foo const &) = delete;` is a user-declared constructor, so no default constructor is generated by the compiler.